# AppDynamics database agent 4.3.10 error on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, appdynamics

I just testing AppDynamics for my database, I am able get it work on MySQL 5 and SQL Server 2014, but I got a JDBC error on SQL Server 2005.

Here is the error log:

> 06 6月 2017 00:55:59,461 ERROR [AD Thread Pool-Global0] DBAgentPollingForUpdate:30 - Fatal transport error while connecting to URL [/controller/instance/DBAGENT_MACHINE_ID/db-monit
>   or-config/37784]: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: davinci2017060100542331.saas.appdynamics.com:443 failed to respond
>   06 6月 2017 00:55:59,473  WARN [AD Thread Pool-Global0] DBAgentPollingForUpdate:62 - Invalid response for configuration request from controller/could not connect. Msg: Fatal transp
>   ort error while connecting to URL [/controller/instance/DBAGENT_MACHINE_ID/db-monitor-config/37784]
>   06 6月 2017 00:56:00,026  INFO [-Scheduler-3] ADBCollector:141 - DB Collector DBSERVER01 is temporarily disabled.
>   06 6月 2017 00:56:01,026  INFO [-Scheduler-3] ARelationalDBCollector:59 - (Re)initialize the DB collector 'DBSERVER01'.
>   06 6月 2017 00:56:01,040  INFO [-Scheduler-3] MSSqlCollector:74 - Obtained connection for url jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.100:1433
>   06 6月 2017 00:56:01,047  INFO [-Scheduler-3] MSSqlCollector:139 - SQL Server Version = 9.00.5057.00 ( 2005.0 )
>   06 6月 2017 00:57:00,025 ERROR [-Scheduler-1] ADBCollector:172 - ***Error collecting data for database 'DBSERVER01'
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'sys'.***
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
>           at com.singularity.ee.agent.dbagent.collector.db.relational.mssql.AMSSqlCollectorDelegate.collectDBMSMetrics(AMSSqlCollectorDelegate.java:335)
>           at com.singularity.ee.agent.dbagent.collector.db.ADBCollectorDelegate.collectPerMinute(ADBCollectorDelegate.java:88)
>           at com.singularity.ee.agent.dbagent.collector.db.ADBCollector.collect(ADBCollector.java:156)
>           at com.singularity.ee.agent.dbagent.collector.db.ADBCollector.run(ADBCollector.java:139)
>           at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run(AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl.java:122)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>           at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:335)
>           at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask.runAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:152)
>           at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:119)
>           at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
>           at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.run(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:236)
>           at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:694)
>           at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:726)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: It appears as if your application is trying to access some `sys.xxxxx` catalog view which doesn't exist in SQL Server 2005 yet. There's probably very little hope to get this to work...... Also: SQL Server 2005 is **no longer supported** - you should **really** start using more recent versions of SQL Server.

Comment: AppDynamics claim it support SQL 2005. But we will upgrade to SQL 2014 very soon. so let's see if it works after upgrade, thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL 2005 is supported, but this was a bug which was introduced in version 4.3.0. There is currently a diagnostic patch for this issue for supported customers. The fix should be in the next patch level once we isolate the issue. If you'd like support just email help@appdynamics.com and they can assist. Thanks.

Comment: Thx Jonah , finally I upgraded to 2014 instead